# How to add image in android studio without following errors?

Tags: java, android

When I try to insert any photo to the android studio.
Following errors happen:

1. Image shows blank
2. Unable to resize

So please help me! I am suffering from this type of thing from 2days.
[image: ScreenShot]

The xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.buckydroid.image.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/hehe"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you add the photo? There is only an `ImageView` visible.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem.

Comment: Please provide us with the .xml layout file for this Activity.

Comment: I dragged image view widget on the screen, then double clicked on it. Added the image in the src option.

Comment: xml : http://pastebin.com/ty1DkqzT

Comment: Friendly advice: Learn to use XML instead of visual editor. Visual editor will eventually generate crappy XML code, that for the most part might not even work the way you want it. The more complex your layouts get the more difficult and slower it will be to develop them from visual editor, instead manually with XML.

Comment: Yeah, but xml has the file too

Comment: Where is your image file located inside the directory structure? Whats the filename?

Comment: It's in res>mipmap

Comment: I can see the small size of image on the left side of xml code. It means directory seems okay.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8xn42TD.png?1 (You can see that)

Comment: So noone helping me?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

The values set for margins here, combined with:

```
android:layout_height="20dp"
```

Are squeezing your image down really small. The layout frame is only 20dp tall and if you're using the default values for activity_vertical_margin, your using 16dp as margin on either side of the image, leaving no room for your actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `res\drawable` folder(s) for UI graphics and `res\mipmap` for the application icon. See e.g. [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView).

Then instead of

```
android:src="@mipmap/hehe"
```

you shoud use

```
android:src="@drawable/hehe"
```

Bitmaps in `drawable` folder(s) should be simple bitmaps and you can use different sizes for different screen densities. This is explained in more detail [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but basically you can have several `drawable` folders each containing a different size version of the same bitmap for the different densities like:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

Android will automatically pick the most suitable version. You just need to provide them. (Or use just one version of each bitmap if they seem to scale well enough.)

Only the application icons should be mipmaps with all the different sizes in one file.